# connect to icloud calendar using dday.ical in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

am trying to connect to caldav icloud calendar using DDay.iCal.iCalendar.LoadFromUri but i see no results and the application crashes returning a null declaration

Dim ical As New DDay.iCal.iCalendarCollection

```
    ical = DDay.iCal.iCalendar.LoadFromUri(New Uri("https://p04-caldav.icloud.com/"), "username", "password")
```